# Delphi code coverage with Sonar using EMMA

Tags: delphi, jenkins, code-coverage, sonarqube, emma

I've set up a Jenkins-Job that analyses a Delphi project with Sonar. Therefore I use the sonar delphi plugin and so far, this works very well. For code coverage analysis I use [delphi-code-coverage](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/), that generates EMMA reports. So, I also installed the Sonar EMMA-Plugin to get the EMMA results into my Sonar report. But it seems, the EMMA-Plugin is never beeing executed during the job. There is no information in the output, not even that it has been skipped or failed...

Here is a fragment of my pom.xml:

```
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>UnitTests</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>emma</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
<sonar.emma.reportPath>UnitTests</sonar.emma.reportPath>
```

How can I get the EMMA plugin executed (combined with the delphi plugin)? Or is there another way to integrate the EMMA reports into my sonar project?

Comment: The author of the delphi-code-coverage tool writes that "You can integrate the xml report using the Hudson EMMA plugin. The html report can be integrated using the HTML Publisher plugin. " - maybe the author has more information on the required steps and configuration

Answer (score 0):

EMMA plugin only works with Java source code. The Delphi plugin has a built in code coverage tool and I'm pretty sure that can't parse EMMA xml files. It's only compatible with AQTime generated CC report. Please check http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Delphi+Plugin for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But using AQTime for CC analysis is not an option for me. IMHO analysing/parsing an already existing EMMA report doesn't or shouldn't depend on any language. That leads me back to my question: Would there be another way to get the report included in my sonar project?

Comment: I think you should ask this question to Sonar's mailing list. I'm sure that you'll get more accurate answers from the developers of the plugin even the devs of Sonar. http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/